# The Meaning of the Term ``Profound Prayer'' as Used by St. Faustina?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, saint, st-faustina

Entry **(860)** in the Diary of St. Faustina reads as follows:

> There are times in life when the soul finds comfort only in profound prayer. Would that souls knew how to persevere in prayer at such times. This is very important.

What does St. Faustina mean here when she writes ``profound prayer?''

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple - it means "profound prayer".

It would seem to me there is no deeper meaning.

From dictionary.com, the definition of 'profound' is: "of deep meaning; of great and broadly inclusive significance".

In the NIV, the word profound is found in verses Job 9:4, Psalms 92:5, and finally Ephesians 5:32. IN Job, it is describes the LORD's wisdom: "His wisdom is profound, his power vast." In Psalms, it describes his thoughts in a similar way, Paul uses it in Ephesians to describe the comparison between a husband and wife and Christ and the Church.

We can see that God's wisdom is not regular - it is greater than any other, of vast significance - after all, His will decides how history goes down.

But we can rather easily understand Paul's comparison - 2 of the greatest relationships that ever can exist.

Thus, profound prayer is prayer that is of great significance, prayer which could change your life, prayer which is greater than any you have made before.

It is certainly true that having such profound prayer is "very important" and difficult to achieve - yet, as St. Faustina tells us, is important, necessary, even, to survive difficult times.

Profound prayer means exactly that.